# Galois invariant of Tate module

Tags: abelian-varieties, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $V$ be a de Rham representation of $G_K=\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$. By Corollary 3.8.4 of [Bloch and Kato - L-functions and Tamagawa numbers of motives](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/BSDseminar/refs/BKTamagawa.pdf) we know that $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}_p} H_f^1(K,V) = \dim_{\mathbb{Q}_p}( D_\text{dR}(V)/D^+_\text{dR}(V)) + \dim_{\mathbb{Q}_p} H^0(K,V)$.

Now, let $V$ be the rational Tate module of an abelian variety $A$ over $K$. Then again by Bloch–Kato (Example 3.10.1, 3.10.2) we obtain  $D_\text{dR}(V)/D^+_\text{dR}(V) \cong H_e^1(K,V)=H_f^1(K,V)$. This gives us $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}_p} H^0(K,V)=0$, i.e. the Galois invariant of $V$ is trivial.

It seems not true due to a famous theorem of Serre (A.2.4 in [Abelian and $l$-adic representations and elliptic curves](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/%7Edarmon/courses/18-19/gs/serre-mcgill.pdf)) which asserts that for any elliptic curve that has complex multiplication, its Tate module has a non-trivial subspace stable under the Galois action, i.e $H^0(K,V)\neq 0$?

However, I cannot find any error in my claim that $H^0(K,V)=0$ using Bloch-Kato.

Comment: Having a $1$-dimensional subspace (and a complement) does not mean that the Galois action on the subspace is trivial. If $K$ is a finite extension over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ then $E(K)$ has a finite torsion subgroup and hence $H^0(K,V)=0$, whether or not E has cm or any kind of reduction.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich thanks, however Serre's theorem says that the subspace is stable under Galois action (the last theorem in Serre's book).

Comment: The Galois invariant of this 1-dimensional subspace cannot be trivial, hence the Tate module. So in CM case $H^0(K,V) \neq 0$.

Comment: The subspace being Galois invariant is not the same as every point in it being invariant. Put differently, having a 1-dimensional subrepresentation is not the same as having a 1-dimensional trivial subrepresentation.

Comment: I see. Thanks for you both Alex and Chris.